# How to reference C# from VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying reference my c# project from vb.After adding the visual basic project into my solution.

I added the vb project as a reference to the c# project references but when I try to write "using Fatek;" compiler doesn't accept it. I have read all relevant information about this but none of them could solve my problem.

What might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Adding assemblies from other languages don't matter to .NET since all assemblies are compiles to MSIL.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the .NET version of both projects. Right click on the projects on your solution, go to `Properties`, on the `Application` tab check `Target Framework`. A frequent problem is that `.NET X.X` and `.NET X.X Client Profile` are incompatible. Convert them both to the same `.NET X.X`.